# For InstallShield, How can I get a path from the user by browsing the computer?

Tags: installshield

I am packing a plugin for another program, thus I need to get the path of the pre-installed program (proe 4.0) and set an environment with it.
Now I used "Requirement" function in InstallShield to search the file of proe 4.0.
The problem is, this "search" function cannot find the install directory in some of the conditions, such as in a nonstandard installation.
I want to show a dialog with a browse button and a text box to allow the user to define the installation directory themselves. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is very easy for advanced users: use a script project, and in the setup vbs script you can find everything you want.